# PHP regex. Convert [text](url) to <a href="url">text</a>

Tags: php, regex

I need some help converting all instances in a string that looks like this [text](url) into a clickable link like this <a href=“url“>text</a>?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regular exprestion `\[(.*?)\]\s*\((.*?)\)` and replace with `<a href="$2">$1</a>` like so

```
preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\s*\((.*?)\)/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', '[text](url)');
```

`\[(.*?)\]` select anything between [] and store it in first capture group
`\((.*?)\)` select anything between () and store it in first capture group

`$1` use content of first capture group

`preg_replace ( $pattern , $replacement , $subject )`
[take a look](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

[Test if it works for you](https://regex101.com/r/m1lK49/1)

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks you very much

Comment: Note that this code will create fake links for invalid URLs between the `()` part of `[]()`.

Comment: It asumes nobody writes `')'` in url

Comment: That's definitely good to know. But in my case all the links are already validated.

Comment: @NIKO_B then it won't be a problem :)